# E11000 duplicate key error index, want to add another entry to the same id via Discord. MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, pymongo

I am trying to make a small discord.py bot for me and my friends. I have MongoDB linked to the bot and I can enter messages into the database and am subsequently storing our Discord ID into the database. Sadly my current code doesn't allow me to enter several messages. It gives me the E11000 Duplicate key error. Meaning I, myself, (and others) can't enter several messages and have my ID linked to it. I currently have the following code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import urllib.parse
import os
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

bot = commands.Bot('$')

#Changed the url ofcourse#
mongo_url = "mongodb+srv://username:" + urllib.parse.quote_plus("password") + "@cluster0.0000.mongodb.net/test"
cluster = MongoClient(mongo_url)
db = cluster["Bot"]
collection = db["Dictionary"]

@bot.listen()
@commands.has_any_role(743487766796697720, 771483467200069672)
async def on_message(message):
    print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")
    myquery = { "_id": message.author.id }
    if (collection.count_documents(myquery) == 0):
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
        if message.content.startswith('$add'):
            post = {"_id": message.author.id, "Message": message.content}
            collection.insert_one(post)
            await message.channel.send('A new entry has been added!')
```

I tried looking around on the internet but couldn't find anything. So is there a way for me to add messages to an already existing ID that is saved as a unique index.

Comment: The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection. You are trying to create different `post` with the same _id.

Comment: @HanielBaez you're completely right! I was working on this late and wasn't thinking straight. Just reworked the code so that the _id is being saved as the message.id and added another entry for the message.author.name. Thank you very much for your help!